# using `!!` without attaching `rlang`

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-package, rlang

I'm writing a package and one of my functions generates a ggplot. I would like to only import ggplot2 or rlang (without depending on them). After some trial and error I managed to get it to work, but now I'm not sure *why* it works.

So my question is, why does the following code work without directly accessing `!!` with `::`?

```
arg1 <- "Species"
ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(x = Petal.Width, y = !!rlang::sym(arg1))) + 
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "max")
```

My understanding is that in order to access the `!!` function I should have to specify the package with `::`, but this example works so what am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to use `!!` or `rlang` just use `.data[[arg1]]`

Comment: @akrun That's a good point.

Comment: By the time the interpreter gets to the y-argument, the environment has already been augmented by the ggplot call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because ‘rlang’/tidy evaluation doesn’t actually resolve the `!!` operator, it doesn’t even *define* such an operator — and in fact this operator doesn’t even *exist!* It’s just two chained `!` operators which never get evaluated because tidy evaluation uses [non-standard evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#tidy-evaluation). The actual implementation in ‘rlang’ is in C++ and it’s fairly sophisticated to fix mismatches in R’s operator precedence rules, but a simplified version for a subset of the functionality could look something like this:

```
bang = as.name('!')

interpolate_bang_bang = function (expr, envir) {
    if (is.call(expr) && expr[[1L]] == bang) {
        if (is.call(expr[[2L]]) && expr[[2L]][[1L]] == bang) {
            eval(expr[[2L]][[2L]], envir = envir)
        } else {
            expr
        }
    } else {
        expr
    }
}
```

This tests if an unevaluated expression is exactly `!! ‹something›`, and substitutes it with an evaluated version of `‹something›`. The real implementation is more complex since it needs to deal with arbitrarily complex, nested expressions (e.g. `1 + !!x`) and since it does a bunch of other stuff. But the fundamental fact is illustrated above: there’s no `!!` operator. Instead, ‘rlang’ checks whether an unevaluated expression contains two immediately nested calls of the `!` operator.

So even if you wanted to you couldn’t import or attach a `!!` operator.

Comment: Some additional clarification would be helpful. Chaining two `!` operators together produces a logical...e.g. `!!TRUE` returns `TRUE`. Does it function like an escape character in NSE?

Comment: Thirded. I went to the cited reference and could not find a discussion of the use of the "bang=bang" convention. It was mentioned in a discussion of "quosures" but then in the section on quosures there was no mention of it.

Comment: @IRTFM I found a better explanation in section [19.4.6](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#the-polite-fiction-of) of the same manual Konrad linked. But the manual remains elusive here as well.

Comment: @doliv071:  You asked whether `!!` acts like an escape character in NSE.  The answer is that it means whatever the package doing the NSE wants it to mean.  "NSE" just means non-standard:  it is not evaluated the way R evaluates it.  To figure out how it is evaluated, you need to look at the documentation of the package that is evaluating it:  in this case, that's `ggplot2`, because you used it in the `ggplot2::aes()` call.  `ggplot2()` follows the "tidyverse" conventions, which are described in the link Konrad gave.

Comment: @konrad the updated answer makes it clear. Honestly think this code chunk in the manual would actually clarify how bang bang works.

Answer (score 3):

If the `rlang` package is loaded (or even the ggplot2 package is loaded), then using `help("!!")` brings up a help page naming this as the "injection operator" that suggests Konrad Rudolph's answer is <strike>wrong</strike> or at least out-of-sync with the Hadley's version of NSE parlance. The link given in a comment to Konrad's answer is more helpful: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#the-polite-fiction-of.  (Konrad being wrong would be a highly unusual instance.) The "injection operator" as it's called there, is also mentioned on `help("topic-inject-out-of-context").

> `!!` and `!!!` behave specially inside all quoting functions powered by rlang, where they behave like real operators with precedence equivalent to unary `+` and `-`.

In the current instance you can also get the same result with `"! ! "`, which I found odd but is explained by the "polite-fiction" material.

My suspicion is that the simple act of calling `ggplot2::ggplot` will load a bunch of required packages into the accessible set of Namespaces even though you tried to prevent that by using the "::" method. So the "!!" does get evaluated in the NSE manner despite efforts to prevent that occurring:

```
#In an entirely  base session with only required packages loaded ....
ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(x = Petal.Width))
#-----------------------------------
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_2.0.2   tidyselect_1.1.2 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_2.0-3 R6_2.5.1         rlang_1.0.2     
 [7] fansi_1.0.2      dplyr_1.0.8      tools_4.1.2      grid_4.1.2       gtable_0.3.0     utf8_1.2.2      
[13] cli_3.2.0        DBI_1.1.2        ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1 digest_0.6.29    tibble_3.1.6    
[19] lifecycle_1.0.1  crayon_1.5.0     purrr_0.3.4      ggplot2_3.3.5    vctrs_0.3.8      glue_1.6.2      
[25] labeling_0.4.2   compiler_4.1.2   pillar_1.7.0     generics_0.1.2   scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: I think this correct ... loading the package namespace doesn't allow me to access functions e.g. `sym()` directly without `::` because it is a function. But since `!!` "isn't a function" the simple loading of the namespace actually gives access to this operator. ... If I understand correctly.

Comment: The documentation text definitely doesn’t imply that my answer is wrong. :-) (Although it does talk about non-existent “operators” to keep the fiction alive.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think that the "operation" of "tests if an unevaluated expression is exactly !! ‹something›, and substitutes it with an evaluated version of ‹something›" really makes it an operator. It has a status in the hierarchy of operator. It's an operator for all intents and purposes. (I did strike out the assertion that you were "wrong" and I agree that you may well be correct in the context of discussing what the R parser does.)

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, I agree that calling it an operator in this context makes sense. What I wanted to be clear on is that it’s not an operator as far as *R itself* is concerned. The R parser only sees it as two distinct operator calls, and it isn’t defined as an operator function in R code (in fact ‘rlang’ *does* define an `!!` function but that is just a regular function with a weird name, it is *not* an operator definition, and isn’t used as such — it’s only used to create an error message if a user erroneously calls it directly).